# Is there a good / acceptable blog-publishing application on Mac OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, macos

On Windows, there is the pretty good Windows Live Writer.
I have always been told that there is no equivalent on Mac.

What would be the best alternative?

Some details about pros/cons, missing features, cool tips would be appreciated.
I will make this question community wiki.

Comment: I know nothing about Windows Live Writer, but would iWeb fit your needs? It's bundled with every Mac.

Comment: It needs at least to interface with existing blogging platforms, using MetaWeblog API

Comment: On Windows I used to blog using Microsoft Office Word 2010. It has a nice integration with Wordpress but it looks the Office 2011 for Mac is missing this feature.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One of the best applications is [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/) (40$) by Red Sweater Software.
It supports many blog types (including Tumblr), and allows both HTML and Rich Text editing.
I think it also allows editing Wordpress pages and not only blog posts.
It handles image uploading, editing of posts and supports multiple blogs.

Some of the cons of MarsEdit are its HTML editing shortcuts and macros which are a little uncomfortable and a bit too little.

If you're comfortable with HTML, then the known [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) text editor can also be used as an editor for blog posts and then you can either copy/paste from there or use a blogging bundle which will let you upload from there. TextMate can also show you live preview of your HTML in a separate window.

Of course, being a specialized application, MarsEdit is more feature rich in the blogging sense but TextMate has a better editor (obviously).

Comment: seems like MarsEdit is the most used/standard/best option for now

Answer (score 6):

Blogo, which was discontinued earlier, is back again. If you are on a Mac looking for a blog editor app, you should try it. You can download the beta for free at:

http://www.getblogo.com

There is also a cross platform solution called [BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) that looks promising.

My current recommendation and favorite is [Blogo](http://www.drinkbrainjuice.com/blogo).

> Easily publish text, images, videos, slideshows and more. 
>   With a simple, intuitive interface and support for Wordpress, Blogger, Typepad, Typo, Drupal, Joomla, and Expression Engine, Blogo is the best 
>   way to maintain your blog and spread the word with Twitter, Ping.fm and other supported services.

It also supports Twitter.

The closest to WLW would be [Ecto](http://illuminex.com/ecto/), but active development seems to have stopped.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard great things about MarsEdit, but have never used it myself. One that I have used quite a bit is [MacJournal](https://www.marinersoftware.com/products/macjournal/), which I know has blog-publishing support (in addition to functioning as a journal and/or notebook, which is what I mostly use it for). Without having put a lot of effort into figuring it out, I do feel like formatting posts can be a bit of a hassle in MacJournal, but I have used it for LJ publishing with okay results. All in all, I have probably heard more good things about MarsEdit for blog-publishing, but figured MacJournal deserved being mentioned, at least, as an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

### Byword 2

In [Byword 2](http://bywordapp.com), you can publish your Markdown content directly to blogs such as WordPress (both self-hosted and WordPress.com), and Tumblr.

[image: Byword Publishing]

Answer (score 2):

### [Qumana](http://www.qumana.com/)

> This simple desktop editing tool allows you to write and save posts to your hard drive, while also posting to any of your blogs, anywhere. Never lose a post again.

### [Thingamablog](http://www.thingamablog.com/)

> A cross-platform (Linux, Mac, Windows), standalone blogging application that makes authoring and publishing your weblogs almost effortless. Unlike most blogging solutions, Thingamablog does NOT require a third-party blogging host, a cgi/php enabled web host, or a MySQL database. In fact, all you need to setup, and manage, a blog with Thingamablog is FTP, SFTP, or network access to a web server.

### [PixelPumper](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/pixelpumper/id595901917?mt=12)

> With PixelPumper, you can now create, edit and publish your blog posts directly from OS X in a beautiful retina display interface. It doesn't matter if you host your blog on WordPress.com or self-host, PixelPumper allows you to post to either.

Just like Live Writer helps you update your WordPress blogs easily while still being inside your desktop environment and not opening the browser. The app is available for free in the Mac App Store and measures only about 4.8 MB in size.

**Edit**

Also of interest is **Ghost:**

More information about it can be seen from its [Kickstarter campaign](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/johnonolan/ghost-just-a-blogging-platform) and [Official website](https://ghost.org/).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Markdown, you can try [WordMark](http://wordmark.liuhao.im). It supports publishing to Wordpress, Ghost, Evernote, Blogger, and so on..

[image: WordMark - A markdown editor for Mac/Windows]

Answer (score 0):

MarsEdit: MarsEdit is a widely used blog-publishing application for macOS. It supports various blogging platforms, including WordPress, Blogger, and more. It offers a rich text editor, media management, and features for easy content creation and publishing.

Blogo: Blogo is another macOS app designed for bloggers. It supports platforms like WordPress, Medium, and Blogger. Blogo provides a distraction-free writing environment, media management, and social media integration for [tris de hoy](https://resultadosdeltris.net/).

Ulysses: While primarily known as a writing app, Ulysses can also be used for blog publishing. It offers a clean writing interface, Markdown support, and the ability to export content to various blogging platforms.

Answer (score -1):

[SmartXBlog](http://smartxblog.com/) is desktop blog editor for both Windows and Mac. It has WYSIWYG editor, image editor, online content search and RSS feed available from nearly 100 popular websites and you can even add your own RSS and drag and drop your result to editor. I think it is best available blogging desktop editor for Windows and Mac.

Comment: I stopped listening to the intro video when it got to before you can use it you have to go and download and install Adobe Air. :-)