# Is there any alternative to Windows Live Writer?

Tags: software-recommendation, windows, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a good / acceptable blog-publishing application on Mac OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/438/is-there-a-good-acceptable-blog-publishing-application-on-mac-os-x)

Coming from Windows, I've quite got used to writing to my blog using Windows Live Writer, which offers the ability to directly publish to the CMS.

Is there any such alternative for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still tied in both OS/X and Win environments going against Wordpress, [Ecto](http://illuminex.com/ecto/) is pretty good.  [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/) was so so.  Both approach with a classic single-document-interface problem of cramming too much stuff on one screen.

I still prefer Live Writer.